# Sorting complete ArrayLists of Integer-permutations into an decision-tree-structure

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, tree, permutation

Background: I have an `ArrayList<Integer>`. The `Integer`s are reference-IDs to some order objects. Later, this list will tell a branch-and-bound-algorithm, which order to plan first into the schedule, which second etc..
B&B is a tree based algorithm i want to use as depth-first search.

So, i need every permutation of the list. My first try used recursion:

```
private List<List<Integer>> permutations(List<Integer> input) {

    List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    if (input.size() == 0) {
        permutations.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        return permutations;
    }

    Integer firstElement = input.remove(0);

    List<List<Integer>> recursiveReturn = permutations(input);
    for (List<Integer> li : recursiveReturn) {

        for (int index = 0; index <= li.size(); index++) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(li);
            temp.add(index, firstElement);
            permutations.add(temp);
        }

    }
    return permutations;
}
```

and gets output for 3 orders:

```
[1, 2, 3] 
[2, 1, 3] 
[2, 3, 1] 
[1, 3, 2] 
[3, 1, 2] 
[3, 2, 1]
```

But in case of depth-first search, i need:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]  
[2, 1, 3] 
[2, 3, 1] 
[3, 1, 2] 
[3, 2, 1]
```

so that my tree nodes will be visited as expected:
[image]

So how can i sort my recursively gotten `Lists` into that structure?

Comment: Is input always sorted and if not do you want the resulting permutations sorted? Or do you want if input is 1, 3, 2 the ouput [1, 3, 2] [1, 2, 3]  [3, 1, 2] [3, 2, 1] [2, 1, 3]  [2, 3, 1]

Comment: Input is not always sorted, the permutations should be sorted as described, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to come up with an algorithm that gets the permutations from the original input list in the correct order. it does not rely on the list contents being ordered.

```
private List<List<Integer>> permutations(List<Integer> input)
{
    List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
    // if input's size is one, then there is only one permutation to return
    // wrap it as single entry inside permutations and return 
    if (input.size() == 1) {
        permutations.add(input);
        return permutations;
    }

    // if input's size is more than one, then we need to calc permutations
    // we iterate over the input, each time taking out one cell
    // the remaining cells become tree "under" this cell
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> remainingCells = new ArrayList<>(input);
        Integer firstElement = remainingCells.remove(i);
        List<List<Integer>> permutationsUnderFirstElement = permutations(remainingCells);
        for (List<Integer> permutation : permutationsUnderFirstElement) {
            permutation.add(0, firstElement);
            permutations.add(permutation);
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to sort existed permutations:

```
final List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
permutations.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
permutations.add(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2));
permutations.add(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3));
permutations.add(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 1));
permutations.add(Arrays.asList(3, 1, 2));
permutations.add(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1));

System.out.println("initial state=" + permutations);

Collections.reverse(permutations);

System.out.println("after shuffle=" + permutations);

final List<List<Integer>> result = permutations.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
    final int length = o1.size();
    int diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        diff = o1.get(i) - o2.get(i);
        if (diff != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("sorted again =" + result);
```

How to generate sorted permutations ([gist](https://gist.github.com/kjkrol/9c4199081eb2d5db7a99)):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * @author Karol Krol
 */
public class Permutation {

    private Permutation() {
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> permutation(final int[] numbers) {
        final PermutationCollector permutationCollector = new PermutationCollector();
        permutation(new int[0], numbers, permutationCollector);
        return permutationCollector.getResult();
    }

    private static void permutation(int[] prefix, int[] array, final Consumer<int[]> operation) {
        int length = array.length;
        if (length == 0) {
            operation.accept(prefix);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                final int[] newPrefix = append(prefix, array[i]);
                final int[] reducedArray = reduce(array, i);
                permutation(newPrefix, reducedArray, operation);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] append(int[] array, int element) {
        int newLength = array.length + 1;
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newLength);
        array[newLength - 1] = element;
        return array;
    }

    private static int[] reduce(int[] array, int index) {
        final int newLength = array.length - 1;
        if (index == 0) {
            return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
        } else {
            final int[] dest = new int[newLength];
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, dest, 0, index);
            System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, dest, index, newLength - index);
            return dest;
        }
    }

    public static class PermutationCollector implements Consumer<int[]> {

        private List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void accept(int[] ints) {
            result.add(IntStream.of(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        public List<List<Integer>> getResult() {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```